# Show values in ComboBox with thousands seperator

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
        A          B
1    ComboBox1
2      1.000
3     10.000
4    100.000
5
```

This list is loaded into a ComboBox using the following VBA:

```
Sub UserForm_Activate()
ComboBox1.List = Sheet1.Range("A2:A4").Value
End Sub
```

All this works fine so far.

---

The issue I have now is that the values in range A2:A4 are using a thousands seperator but when I load it into the ComboBox the thousands seperator are deleted. How can I display the values in my ComboBox with the thousands seperator as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the thausand separators, you can format the values to strings and put the separator there. This is dones with the format function - `Format(10000, "#,##0.00")`. Then the values should be saved as array of strings and this array is the one, which is passed as a source to the `UserForm.Combobox1.List`:

```
Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Dim myArr As Variant
    Dim myRng As Range

    Set myRng = Range("A1:A4")
    ReDim myArr(myRng.Cells.Count)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
        myArr(i) = Format(myRng.Cells(i + 1), "#,##0.00")
    Next i

    ComboBox1.List = myArr

End Sub
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]